# Laravel mix shows error after compiling assets on M2 with latest Node

Tags: node.js, laravel-mix

I am running latest laravel-mix on Apple Silicon M2. I tried it with Node 18.18.1 (NPM 9.8.1) , And 20.8.0 (NPM 10.1.0) as well. When I run `npx mix` it compiles but also give the bellow error (Screenshot Bellow)
[image]

I also fresh installed Laravel-Mix in a new folder, it gives the same error at the end after compiling.